# useing sqlmap on mac

Tags: python, sqlmap

I have installed python3 on my mac.

But when I use sqlmap, I get

> wrong initialization of pymsql detected (using Python3 dependencies)

Comment: "Tip" or error?

Comment: Oh my mistake . is a error

Comment: How did you install sqlmap?

Comment: I downloaded it from https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show the command you use to sqlmap?

On my Mac, I have both Python 2.7 and Python 3 installed and have to invoke Python3 explicitly via:

```
python3 <scriptName>
```

Because just using 'python' defaults to python 2.7.

In ref to OP's comment about first line of script using #!/usr/bin/env python

This is exactly my point, that on the Mac this defaults to **Python 2.7** but you need to run sqlmap with Python3

Notice 2.7.10 below:

```
/usr/bin/env python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: just use "./sqlmap.py -d xxx" because on the top of the sqlmap.py there is a bash command "#!/usr/bin/env python".I have both 2.7 and 3.5 too.The same with you , if I want to use python3 I also use "python3 xxx.py"

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem.

Maybe because I installed python3 on my mac,so when I installed pip on my mac it downloaded PyMySQL and PyMySQL3 lib.

The interesting thing is that when I use the command "pip list",it showed that "PyMYSQL3" in the list.But I can't use "pip uninstall PyMySQL" to uninstall it.
It will tell you the path when you try to remove it.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgY7A.jpg)

it was not "Permission defined".Just cd the path and remove the PyMysql3 lib that you can normally use the sqlmap with pymysql.